# Side-to-side figure and table in beamer problem

Tags: beamer, positioning, minipage

```
\begin{figure}
    %\centering
        \begin{minipage}[h]{0.58\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4,trim=12mm 15mm 12mm 15mm]{fig1}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[h]{0.38\textwidth}
        \centering
        \include{fig2}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

I get the fig1 nicely placed in the center of the left side BUT fig2 'sank' at the bottom of the right side. I dont really know what's wrong with the code. Actually fig2 is a table which i store as a tex file with codes only, something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    aa  & bb  \\ \hline
    0 & 10 \\ \hline
    1 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Hope someone will help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @lockstep thanks for the tip. i was about to do it. too rush to post the question.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't sure if you knew this feature, but I should have waited 5 minutes nevertheless.

Comment: @lockstep dont worry about that.. the more important thing is to get the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest that you use

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} % So the demo works!
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = 2 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = 2 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

instead?

Comment: i tried this (of course after you suggest). ehm... it doesnt work. actually fig2 is a table which i store in a tex file, with a code sth like in the questions (sorry, just add this)

Comment: @hotaru: then, please edit your question and include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem. I ask you for this MWE since I used a solution similar to the one by 5gon12eder and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You want the optional argument to the `column` environment:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height = 2 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height = 1 cm]{demo}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(`beamer` manual, section 12.7)

Answer (score 0):

The [subfig package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) is excellent for side-by-side figures and tables.

There is a nice example here: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats

Comment: if you mean that advice as an answer, it would be great if you would rephrase it, since this question to the OP looks like a comment. It would be good to elaborate it, besides posting a link.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't have the required reputation to comment under the question yet. Also, the example link does go straight to a relevant code snippet, so copy-and-pasting it seemed unnecessary - I did not realize this violated etiquette.